# What is the best way to store data offline on android apps?

Tags: android, database

I am a beginner on Android development, I should develop an application that works without connection. What's the best form of data that I should use(JSON, SQLite, or Firebase)?
My application aims to translate text in the Latin language to the English language in real time. So I should store for each letter in English all the corresponding forms in Latin and this is the table that I should store: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpx5r.png)

Comment: It depends on the type, format, and amount of data to be stored.  There's no one answer, any of those could be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

This is a quite a vague question which makes it difficult to answer. Really SO is best suited to a specific question with much more detail.

In short Android has a variety of offline storage options

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- SqLite Database

All have various pros and conns, have a read here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You can also use a third party solution such as firebase, parse, google ect. All have their perks, it depends on your needs.

Good luck.

Comment: My application aims to translate text in latin language to the english language in real time .So i should store for each letter in english all  the corresponding forms in latin  and the app should works offline to be used even without connection.I hope that the idea become clear and you will help me .

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion SQLite is a good way to store data offline, but if you'd want to save just a few Strings or something like that then it can also be done by using SharedPreferences.

Comment: With sqlite can i store data with type "image" ?

Comment: As far as I know it is possible with the use of a BLOB variable

Comment: Thank you a lot Dennis .

Answer (score 0):

Well Pal! its completely depends upon the type of App you want to develop but in my opinion the best way to store the data is using Sqlite database if you are storing user related information or if you are storing session (application) data then you should use SharedPrefrences instead. Hope this would help!!:)

Comment: My application aims to translate text in latin language to the english language in real time .So i should store for each letter in english all the corresponding forms in latin and the app should works offline to be used even without connection.I hope that the idea become clear and you will help me

Comment: In this scenario you must use SQlite database to store all the forms corresponding to each english letter as the amount of data must be great.